# Evaluating inline source code in Title

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to make my document title dynamic, for instance like this :

```
#+Title: Annual report for year  src_emacs-lisp{(- (string-to-number (format-time-string "%Y")) 1)}
```

Should render as :

### Annual report for year 2020

Comment: Render where? In the Org mode buffer? In an exported file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `orgmode` [macro](https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html) for this. It supports evaluating elisp code like this:

> #+MACRO: year (eval (format-time-string "%Y"))
> #+TITLE: Annual Report for {{{year}}}

There's a built-in macro for rendering the time a document is exported, which takes a time format as an argument. This should handle your particular example:

> #+TITLE: Annual Report for {{{time(%Y)}}}

You can also use the built-in `date` macro, which allows you to format the value of the `DATE` keyword:

> #+TITLE: Annual Report for {{{date(%Y)}}}
> #+DATE: <2020-02-25 Thu>

In order to format the `date` macro, the `DATE` keyword must be a timestamp. This would allow you to set the date in the DATE keyword, and have that value be rendered in the title, or other places in the document. Those values would stay the same no matter when you rendered the document, while the value for the `time` macro will be updated to reflect the latest rendering.